# FAILED Binder Transaction on spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a fragment with 12 Spinners and a button, I need to set the item selected position to zero but I'm getting a binder transaction error when I click the button.
Would you tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

I just simplified the code and deleted 10 of the spinners code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Load defaults
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zone_types,container,false);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.zoneTypes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //---------------- ZONE 1 --------------------
    Spinner SpinnerZ1 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerZ1Type);
    SpinnerZ1.setAdapter(adapter);
    SpinnerZ1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
        {
            if(SpinnerZ1.getSelectedItemPosition()>0)
            {
                //Se eligio un tipo de zona
                SpinnerZ1.setBackgroundColor(0xb000A000);
            }
            else
            {
                //No se eligio nada
                SpinnerZ1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCFE2F3);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
        {
        }
    });
    //---------------- ZONE 1 --------------------
    //---------------- ZONE 2 --------------------
    Spinner SpinnerZ2 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerZ2Type);
    SpinnerZ2.setAdapter(adapter);
    SpinnerZ2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
        {
            if(SpinnerZ2.getSelectedItemPosition()>0)
            {
                //Se eligio un tipo de zona
                SpinnerZ2.setBackgroundColor(0xb000A000);
            }
            else
            {
                //No se eligio nada
                SpinnerZ2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCFE2F3);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
        {
        }
    });
    //---------------- ZONE 2 --------------------
    //---------------- Button --------------------
    Button DeselBtn = view.findViewById((R.id.buttonDelete));
    DeselBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(DeselBtn.performClick())
            {
                SpinnerZ1.setSelection(0);
                SpinnerZ2.setSelection(0);
            }
        }
    });
    //---------------- Button --------------------
    return view;
}
```

Comment: In general, if you are getting a crash, your question should include the full stack trace, as those details may make it easier for others to help you. In terms of your problem, you seem to have an infinite loop: your `OnClickListener` calls `performClick()`, which will trigger the `OnClickListener`, which calls `performClick()`,  which will trigger the `OnClickListener`, which calls `performClick()`,  which will trigger the `OnClickListener`, which calls `performClick()`,  which will trigger the `OnClickListener`, which calls `performClick()`, etc.

Comment: Hahaha! What a noob. Thanks! I was thinking that performClick() was the event and I was already inside the event onClick(). Now is running OK.